# I want to pass data from blade to controller using jquery ajax method but i get an error like [object Object]. How can i solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to get the value of `#search` id and pass it through url `{{ route('admin.auto.fetch') }}` but it fails.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#list', function() {
  $('#search').val($(this).text())
  var item_Id = $('#search').val().split("#>")[1];

  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('admin.auto.fetch') }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      item_Id: item_Id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Saved");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert('failed');
      alert(error);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the error? Seeing `[object Object]` as a string means that the object you're sending has been coerced to a string instead od serialised correctly. What is the value of `#list` which is applied to `#search` and then `split()`?

Comment: In your ajax, try `data: JSON.stringify({
      item_Id: item_Id
    })`

Comment: In form Submit, You have to pass ```csrf_token()``` in data.

Comment: It seems the error happened into error callback. Paste your script in controller and go ahead. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I Agree with @BhoomiPatel, you must to pass the csrf token like a data 
`"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"` inside your `data` field